# Email into spam at amazon server

Tags: php, email

I have an application and I have hosted that at amazon server. I have a form by which our customer will contact to admin. As customer will fill this form and submit then email will be send to admin but all emails marked as spam if I will use a self designed template. If I will use simple text what ever typed by user then its working fine and coming in to inbox. My template have simple logo and HTML/CSS code.Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: have you checked DKIM and spf email validator ?

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

you can use smtp mail system.

and image of your template have to encoded as inline image.

if you use phpmailer class then use this `MsgHTML($html_msg);` function and your image source must be same server (that means where in mail script).

then this function automatically convert into inline image

And fillup more requirement:

*from address must be real (from addr not reply_to) reply_to may be fake.

*Subject have something

[More Info](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsmtp)